# How to get total download size and loading progress in WebGL?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity3D WebGL, I can get the download progress in   `function UnityProgress(gameInstance, progress)`

1. In this function, I can only get progress, not the actual data downloaded or total data needed to be downloaded. How to get this data?
2. The progress seems to be only for downloading, after downloading, it seems Unity still needs to load those data into memory, is there any way to get progress for that portion?